# Generate the json file out of two txt files

Tags: python, json

I have two different txt files-
1)one with just jpg files
2)another with five cations for each image in the following format:

```
1000268201_693b08cb0e.jpg#0 A child in a pink dress is climbing up a set of stairs in an entry way .
1000268201_693b08cb0e.jpg#1 A girl going into a wooden building .
1000268201_693b08cb0e.jpg#2 A little girl climbing into a wooden playhouse .
1000268201_693b08cb0e.jpg#3 A little girl climbing the stairs to her playhouse .
1000268201_693b08cb0e.jpg#4 A little girl in a pink dress going into a wooden cabin .
```

where 0,1,2,3,4 are caption id's for same image.

I want create something like this for all data:-

`{"images":[
    {"imgurl": "static/img/667626_18933d713e.jpg",
    "description": "A girl is stretched out in shallow water",
    },
    {"imgurl": "static/img/667626_18933d713e.jpg",
    "description": "A girl is stretched out in water",
    },
    {"imgurl": "static/img/667626_18933d713e.jpg",
    "description": "description 3",
    },
    {"imgurl": "static/img/667626_18933d713e.jpg",
    "description": "description 4",
    },
    {"imgurl": "static/img/667626_18933d713e.jpg",
    "description": "description 5",
    }
    ]
}`

I am looking for a python code to do this at once ,for whole dataset.
It is very frustrating to do it manually.

```
import glob

image_database = glob.glob('/static/img/img.jpg')
dataset_list = []
for image in image_database:
    image.show()
    print 'Enter the description':
    description = input()
    img_data = {}
    img_data['imgurl'] = image
    img_data['description'] = description
    dataset_list.append(img_data)
dataset_json = {}
dataset_json['images'] = dataset_list
json.dump(dataset_json, open('custom_dataset.json','wb')
```

I have placed the image.txt under static folder,what i am currently doing is to enter the description manually.

Comment: Why would you need the first file if both the file name and captions are available in the second file?

Comment: Is there a one-to-one mapping between each image name and caption?

Comment: Yes i dont need first file involved here,as image name is in second file.

Comment: yes there is one on one mapping. those jpg file names in second are present in the first file

Comment: basically i need to parse the second file to get it in the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the file and generate your json.

```
import json

filepath = 'img.txt'
asset_path = 'static/img/'
images = []
with open(filepath) as file:
    for line in file:
        split = line.split("#")
        image = {
            "imgurl": asset_path+split[0],
            "description": split[1].strip('\n')
        }
        images.append(image)

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump( { "images" : images }, outfile)
```